# I am facing problem installing linux-image-amd64 i just upgraded my kali linux machine to 2020.2

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade, dpkg

[image: i have tried dpkg --purge linux-image-5.5.0-kali2-amd64]

also i have tried `apt autoremove` but can't remove the older packages i keep getting dependency errors

the commands i tried are:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

but same error again
Also when i run `dpkg --configure -a` i get this error

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-5.6.0-kali1-amd64 (= 5.6.7-1kali1); however:
  Package linux-image-5.6.0-kali1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-amd64
```

the output of `ls -l /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools` is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Feb 6 2019 /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools
```

The root file system is not full it has 33.8 GB space left. I am using kali-linux (persistent) using usb.

Comment: There's a yet-to-be-found cause that isn't provided. My first step would be to reinstall the package initramfs-tools providing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools: `apt-get --reinstall install initramfs-tools` . Might also require the additional flag `--fix-broken` if it won't even execute the previous command. Be careful and don't accept to run it if it offers to remove several important packages

Comment: @A.B u see that's the problem i cant install or reinstall anything bcoz whenever i run apt-get install "package" i am asked the following:  ```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.5.0-kali2-amd64
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 1 to remove and 79 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/50.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 282 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]``` and if i choose Y dpkg returns error.

Comment: @A.B OK thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I solved this problem I found that while upgrading my kali machine It had an unfortunate shutdown which led to some missing files In linux-image 5.5.0 and caused the config problem. I simply removed all the info of Linux-image -5.5.0 from Dpkg and on tried `apt-get update` and `apt autoremove` and it solved this issue.